# How to extract images into dataframe with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do you extract images and put them in a dataframe from the website Asos? I hope the header is ok

```
def asos(soup_in):
    # Image
    image_div = soup_in.find_all('img', class_='_2r9Zh0W', alt=True)


    for container1 in image_div:
        container1 = container1["src"]
        print(container1)
        image.append(container1)

url = "https://www.asos.com/men/t-shirts-vests/cat/?cid=7616&nlid=mw%7Cclothing%7Cshop%20by%20product%7Ct-shirts%20%26%20vests&page=1"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0"}
results = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
asos(soup, brand_names)


asos_t_shirt = pd.DataFrame({
    'Images': image,

})
```

It currently returns four random images in the usingthe src tag

//images.asos-media.com/products/levis-2-horses-t-shirt-in-red/21167073-1-red?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain
//images.asos-media.com/products/levis-spaced-t-shirt-in-light-blue/21168144-1-lightblue?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain
//images.asos-media.com/products/tommy-hilfiger-large-patch-broken-flag-box-embroid-logo-long-sleeve-top-in-white/23377256-1-white?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain
//images.asos-media.com/products/tommy-jeans-big-tall-corp-logo-t-shirt-in-twilight-navy/23456611-1-twilightnavy?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain

The class in the html looks like this

```
<img alt="" class="_2r9Zh0W" data-auto-id="productTileImage" sizes="(min-width: 768px) 317px, 238px" src="//images.asos-media.com/products/under-armour-training-lockertag-logo-t-shirt-in-red/21982249-1-red?$n_480w$&amp;wid=476&amp;fit=constrain" srcset="//images.asos-media.com/products/under-armour-training-lockertag-logo-t-shirt-in-red/21982249-1-red?$n_240w$&amp;wid=238&amp;fit=constrain 238w,//images.asos-media.com/products/under-armour-training-lockertag-logo-t-shirt-in-red/21982249-1-red?$n_320w$&amp;wid=317&amp;fit=constrain 317w,//images.asos-media.com/products/under-armour-training-lockertag-logo-t-shirt-in-red/21982249-1-red?$n_480w$&amp;wid=476&amp;fit=constrain 476w,//images.asos-media.com/products/under-armour-training-lockertag-logo-t-shirt-in-red/21982249-1-red?$n_640w$&amp;wid=634&amp;fit=constrain 634w,//images.asos-media.com/products/under-armour-training-lockertag-logo-t-shirt-in-red/21982249-1-red?$n_750w$&amp;wid=714&amp;fit=constrain 714w,//images.asos-media.com/products/under-armour-training-lockertag-logo-t-shirt-in-red/21982249-1-red?$n_960w$&amp;wid=952&amp;fit=constrain 952w">
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have requests already imported you can run

```
r = requests.get(img_url, allow_redirects=False)
```

on any of the four addresses you got (although I would discard anything after a question mark) and the content of the image (which is a .webp image file) will be stored
as

```
img = r.contents
```

So you could then save it as a .webp file somewhere on your disk and store its path in the datafrime or assign its value (long string of characters) to a cell in DataFrame. Webp format is not the most popular one for all purposes so you might be interested in some conversion using PIL or other tools.